# Sync local Database and remote Application through unstable network

Tags: java, mysql, sql, postgresql, network-programming

I need to sync a local PostgreSQL database to a remote application.

We have a device used in field service management. This device collects all kind of data and stores it in a local PostgreSQL database. This data needs to be transferred to a remote application (preferably in real time). Unfortunately most of the times we do not have a static internet connection (mostly it is 2G/GSM).

I tried using SOAP Web-Services and transmitted each line individually. The bonus was that I got the result back and I could also store locally if the set/line was copied.

It seems that this approach has a lot of overhead to it, though and therefore I am looking for a better way to do this. I don't mind using other technologies, different libraries or SQL-Statements directly but it needs to be done in JAVA.

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [SymmetricDS](https://www.symmetricds.org) for database replication. It's supports heterogeneous schema definitions and is pretty reliable. It's written in Java, you can use it embedded on you application.

A quote from the [faqs](https://www.symmetricds.org/docs/faq):

> **Does replication require a fast network connection?**
>
> No, the network connection can be slow and even unreliable for periods of time.
>   SymmetricDS makes efficient use of the network with low overhead,
>   batching of data, and data compression. It is designed to withstand
>   periods of network outage by tracking changes that were unsuccessful
>   and retrying.

I'd suggest you to take a look on its [Quick Start Guide](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/tutorials.html) to a overview.